# Python Launcher shows nothing on the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, python

I installed python 3 in Mac OS. When I first time ran a python program using Python Launcher, it asked for something like printing access to terminal. I declined it. Now when I run any python program, it opens the terminal, executes the program, but doesn't show any output. I tried searching in the settings to give Python Launcher the access but didn't found anything.

How do I give Terminal access to Python Launcher?

Comment: When you run pythonLauncher without a script it shows a preferences Window - that should give what to alter.

Answer (score 1):

When you run python launcher you should get a set of menu items. Go to the Python Launcher menu item and under that select Preferences. The panel that appears should look like the image below.

[image]

As you can see there is a checkbox to run in a terminal window.

Comment: This option is always marked, and in fact, it also runs in terminal. The problem is about printing the output in the terminal